# formatt a text field with css and apply an indent to outer border?

Tags: css

does anyone know any way in which to apply a css style indent and a border glow (when active) to a textarea field?

i am trying to style a textarea box using pure css

```
.field{
width:150px;
height:20px;
border:1px solid #c6c6c6;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
padding-left:5px;
padding-right:4px;

}

.field:active {
width:150px;
height:20px;
border:4px solid #blue;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
padding-left:5px;
padding-right:4px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `:focus`, not `:active`, to style an input that a user is controlling. `:active` only fires when the item is clicked, so it won't affect an input area that the user has tabbed to or is currently typing in.

To achieve a glow, rather than a solid border, you can use `box-shadow`.

```
.field:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px blue;
    outline: 0; /* optionally remove or change the outline */
}
```

I'm not clear on exactly how you want to indent text, but you can use `text-indent` to do that.

[Here's a jsFiddle of the above.](http://jsfiddle.net/johntobinme/wekx4/)

*Note: there is a mistake in your CSS - a hex color begins with a hash `#` but a named one does not, ie. `#blue` is incorrect.*